# Power bi % in table from a measure

Tags: dax, measure

I need to calculate % for each value from "G. Directos Año Actual" from the measure "Ventas Año Actual"
Imagen adjunta

Answer (score 0):

That is very little information to go on, but assuming "G. Directos Año Actual" is a column that can be used as a dimension for the "Ventas Año Actual" measure, and that column is providing row context in whatever visual you use, this will get you the % of total for each G. Directos Año Actual.

```
% of Ventas Año Actual = DIVIDE(
    [Ventas Año Actual]
    , CALCULATE([Ventas Año Actual], REMOVEFILTERS('Unknown Table Name'[G. Directos Año Actual]))
)
```

Comment: Thanx Dani U.
"G. Directos Año Actual" is a measure too.
G. Directos Año Actual = CALCULATE(SUM('Saldos'[Valor]),'TABLA EQUIVALENCIA'[REPARTO]="GASTOSFIJOS")